# Will either of these displays work on the Raspberry Pi DSI connector?

Tags: lcd, dsi, lvds

I came across two different DSI LCD touchscreens ([1](https://www.pine64.org/?product=7-lcd-touch-screen-panel), [2](https://ameridroid.com/collections/closeouts/products/banana-7-0-in-lcd-touchscreen-1024x600)), but I'm not clear if they will work on the Raspberry Pi, but more importantly, I'm not clear on what specs i should be looking at the check if they are compatible or not.  From what I can tell, their physical interface is compatible, but I suspect that there would be missing drivers or missing support somewhere else in the chain.

The Banana Pro [specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_Pro#Banana_Pi_Pro) say "LVDS/RGB/CPU display interface (DSI)". The [product page](https://www.pine64.org/?page_id=61454) for the RockPro64 says it has a "MIPI-DSI 2560*1600 +Touchpanel port".

How do I determine if a DSI display is compatible with my DSI enabled SBC? For example, a Raspberry Pi.  Do I just need the correct drivers?

Answer (score 3):

They won't work. The only supported display is the one created by the Raspberry Pi Foundation and sold by their usual distributors.